# Extracting words from a string in r

Tags: r, text, frame, cpu-word

I have the following text as an example in every row of my data frame, df:

```
[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Soccer'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Basketball'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Boxing'}]
```

Is there any way to extract words (Soccer, Basketball, Boxing) from this text? Sorry I am new to text analysis in R.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all(string,"\\w+(?='\\})")` should work

Comment: It works but is giving me the answer like c("Soccer", "Basketball", "Boxing"). How can I make it "Soccer", "Basketball", "Boxing"?

Comment: just do `unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(string,"\\w+(?='\\})"))`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a JSON input string. You can parse the JSON string with `jsonlite::fromJSON`, and extract the relevant column `name`:

```
# Sample string
ss <- "[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Soccer'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Basketball'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Boxing'}]";

# Parse JSON
library(jsonlite);
df <- fromJSON(txt = gsub("'", "\"", ss));

# Extract words
df$name;
#[1] "Soccer"     "Basketball" "Boxing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following.

```
x <- "[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Soccer'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Basketball'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Boxing'}]"
g <- gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+", x)
y <- unlist(regmatches(x, g))
y[y != "id" & y != "name"]
#[1] "Soccer"     "Basketball" "Boxing"
```

Another possibility for this last instruction would be to use `%in%`.

```
y[!y %in% c("id", "name")]
#[1] "Soccer"     "Basketball" "Boxing"
```

Like this you could have a vector of unwanted strings, such as `c("id", "name")`, and avoid a long conjunction `&`.

Comment: just do `regmatches(x,gregexpr("\\w+(?='\\})",x,perl = T))`

Comment: It works but is giving me the answer like c("Soccer", "Basketball", "Boxing"). How can I make it "Soccer", "Basketball", "Boxing"?

Comment: @user36729 The vector `"Soccer", "Basketball", "Boxing"` in R is formed with the combine function `c()`. Meaning, `c("Soccer", "Basketball", "Boxing")` is a way to create the vector, not the vector itself. When you say that it is giving the answer `c(etc)`, can you explain it better?